# Android Tetris (Ghost Piece/Shadow Piece)

Tags: java, android, 2d-games, tetris

I would like to know how I can add a Shadow Piece/ Ghost Piece - This is the piece that leads to show where the falling piece will land should the player do a fastdrop.

I'm doing an android game of Tetris - I'm using the project from https://github.com/Linus1905/Android-Tetris.

I will really appreciate

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the same logic you would for a "fast drop." Loop by decreasing the piece's y coordinate one row at a time. Stop when you detect a collision below. Don't insert the piece into the game board. Instead, simply change those cells' colors/shading.